# How to save a intersection between layers in a shp file?

Tags: shapefile, pyqgis, pyshp

I have calculated the intersection between polygons in different layers, I got it, and now, I need to save the intersection in a new shp file. I have tried to use QgsVectorFileWriter(), however, I haven´t had good results. It´s difficult to prove because the layers are enormous and everytime I try to run my script takes around 15 minutes. So I want to know if someone knows how can I save this file in a shp file?

This is my code,

```
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-
import timeit
start = timeit.default_timer()

layer1=None
for lyr in QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers().values():
    if lyr.name() == "ENTIDAD_1":
    #if lyr.source() == "/path/to/shapefile.shp":
        layer1 = lyr
        break

layer2=None
for lyr in QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers().values():
    if lyr.name() == "ENTIDAD":
    #if lyr.source() == "/path/to/shapefile.shp":
        layer2 = lyr
        break

print layer1.name()
print layer2.name()
selections=[] #declares it is a list
intersecciones=[]

interseccion=None
for f in layer1.getFeatures():
    for a in layer2.getFeatures():
        if a.geometry().intersects(f.geometry()):
            intersection = a.geometry().intersection(f.geometry())# I need to save in a shp this intersection
            print intersection.exportToWkt()
            intersecciones.append([f[2],a[2]])


stop = timeit.default_timer()
print stop - start
```

Comment: It should be using python ?

Answer (score 2):

I modified your code for producing a memory layer (you only have to save it as shapefile):

```
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-
import timeit
start = timeit.default_timer()

layer1=None
for lyr in QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers().values():
    if lyr.name() == "ENTIDAD_1":
    #if lyr.source() == "/path/to/shapefile.shp":
        layer1 = lyr
        break

layer2=None
for lyr in QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers().values():
    if lyr.name() == "ENTIDAD":
    #if lyr.source() == "/path/to/shapefile.shp":
        layer2 = lyr
        break

print layer1.name()
print layer2.name()
selections=[] #declares it is a list
intersecciones=[]

epsg = layer1.crs().postgisSrid()

uri = "Polygon?crs=epsg:" + str(epsg) + "&field=id:integer""&index=yes"

mem_layer = QgsVectorLayer(uri,
                           'intersections',
                           'memory')

prov = mem_layer.dataProvider()

interseccion=None
k = 0
for f in layer1.getFeatures():
    for a in layer2.getFeatures():
        if a.geometry().intersects(f.geometry()):
            feature = QgsFeature()
            intersection = a.geometry().intersection(f.geometry())# I need to save in a shp this intersection
            intersects = intersection.exportToWkt()
            feature.setAttributes([k])
            feature.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromWkt(intersects)) 
            prov.addFeatures([feature])
            print intersection.exportToWkt()
            intersecciones.append([f,a]) #don't have sense this line
            k += 1

QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(mem_layer)

stop = timeit.default_timer()
print stop - start
```

When I ran the code at the Python Console of QGIS it worked well. You can see my results (memory layer is in greenish color):

[image]